# Geometric Relationship Between Speed and Acceleration

Tags: geometry

A plane is traveling at a speed of 625 knots and accelerating by 5 knots each minute and for 10 minutes after.

a. Draw 2 graphs side-by-side to indicate what happens to the acceleration a and the speed s over the period.

**b. Based on your graphs, what geometric relationship can you draw between speed and acceleration. Use any appropriate geometric formulae.**

I'm fine until part b; what is this even asking? I could not find any help on the concept by researching geometric relationships, so i'm just utterly lost as to what this means. Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Comment: What *shape* does the graph of the speed have.  What shape does the graph of the acceleration have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem to be kind of a poorly worded question, but here's two guesses on what the answer should look like, and what the pedagogy is preparing you for.

"The speed is a line with slope 5, and the acceleration is a constant 5. I conjecture that this can be restated as "the slope of the graph of the speed is the same as the acceleration". This is because the geometric equation of a line is $y = mx + b$ and the physical formula for speed is $v = at + v_0$."

My second guess of what the answer looks like runs something like this:

"The area between the graph of acceleration and the x-axis at time $t$ is $at$. Meanwhile, the speed at time $t$ is $at + v_0$. I conjecture that "the speed at time $t$ is the same as the area between the graph of acceleration and the x-axis at time $t$ plus a constant".

As to the pedagogy, what I assume this question is preparing you for is calculus; specifically, how calculus is applied in kinematics. At the risk of getting way ahead of myself, and hugely ignoring mountains of very important mathematics, calculus is considered with the study of two different operation, *differentiation* and *integration*. Differentiation tells you how to go from displacement to velocity, from velocity to acceleration, and so on, while integration tells you how to go from acceleration to velocity and from velocity to displacement. More broadly (but not *too much* more broadly), differentiation tells you how to find the rate of change of some quantity, while integration tells you how to find out how much change has happened. The first answer I gave is focused on differentiation, and the second, integration.